# Why is my colorbox overlay not showing any controls?

Tags: colorbox

I have included the colorbox css and js and it works when I click any image. However, I don't see any button/control on the overlay. It is only the image with dark overlay behind it. What could be going wrong here?

I am doing this in k15t Scroll Viewport for Confluence.

I tried changing the default script values but even that didn't help. Am I supposed to add the controls manually? I don't think so.

I would like to see the default close button along with slideshow effect, etc. that colorbox offers.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. Though dumb but still. The default colorbox images (button icons) folder was residing at a location different from where colorbox expected it. So now, I can see the close button at least.

What still remains is - though I have set the colorbox properties right, I still don't see the previous and next buttons on a page with multiple images. What am I missing? It should have shown up by default...

Thank you.

Comment: For future reference: You need to place the images with the controls in a folder `images` next to the colorbox.css file.